# Geometric meaning of $| |z - z_1| - |z - z_2| | = a$, where $z, z_1, z_2 \in \mathbb C$

Tags: complex-numbers, conic-sections

Find locus of points of $$| |z - z_2| - |z - z_1| | = c, \ \ c < |z_1 - z_2| $$ 
 $a, z_1, z_2$ are constants 
I know, that this is a hyperbola, but I can't show that and bring the equation to canonical form:
$$ \frac{Re(z)^2}{a^2} - \frac{Im(z)^2}{b^2} = 1$$ 
I know, that I can square the equation several times, but I wasted a lot of time, doing this way and didn't get the answer. Is there another way to solve it?

Comment: What you need to have this form are $z_1+z_2=0$ and $z_1,z_2$ are real numbers.

Comment: The algebra may be easier to work with if you first convert all the $z$'s to $x+iy$ form, and then substitute x=Re(z) and y=Im(z) at the end.

Comment: Use the definition of a hyperbola in $\mathbb R^2.$ Then the foci are $z_1$ and $z_2$ and the work has been done for you! (or consult any algebra book for the details)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to define a [hyperbola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola) is

> a set of points, such that for any point $P$ of the set, the absolute difference of the distances $PF_1$, $PF_2$ to two fixed points $F_1$, $F_2$ (the foci) is constant

or, using the complex-plane notation from your question,

> a set of points, such that for any point $z$ of the set, the absolute difference $c$ of the distances $|z - z_1|$, $|z - z_2|$ to two fixed points $z_1$, $z_2$ (the foci) is constant

So yes, the locus is a hyperbola.

The mistake you're making when you try to “bring the equation to canonical form” $\frac{x^2}{a^2} - \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$ is that that form assumes that the two foci are on the x-axis and equidistant from the origin, whereas an arbitrary hyperbola can have its foci *anywhere*.

If you need an explicit equation, it may be helpful to break each complex value into its real ($x$) and imaginary ($y$) components.

$$||z-z_2|−|z-z_1||=c$$
$$||(x+iy)-(x_2+iy_2)|−|(x+iy)-(x_1+iy_1)||=c$$
$$||(x-x_2) + i(y-y_2)|−|(x-x_1) + i(y-y_1)||=c$$
$$| \sqrt{(x-x_2)^2 + (y-y_2)^2} - \sqrt{(x-x_1)^2 + (y-y_1)^2}|=c$$
$$\sqrt{(x-x_2)^2 + (y-y_2)^2} - \sqrt{(x-x_1)^2 + (y-y_1)^2}=±c$$

Now, if you have an equation of the form $\sqrt{u} - \sqrt{v} = w$, then doing some algebra gives you $(w^2 - u -v)^2 = 4uv$, eliminating the inconvenient √ signs.

$$(c^2 -(x-x_2)^2 - (y-y_2)^2 - (x-x_1)^2 - (y-y_1)^2)^2 = 4((x-x_2)^2 + (y-y_2)^2)((x-x_1)^2 + (y-y_1)^2)$$